# Couldn't save associated models in rails using auto_save: true

Tags: rails-activerecord

please consider the following snippet.

I have a parent model named Post as:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true
end
```

Again in the associated comment model I have mentioned as:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

So, when I try to create a comment for a post like:

```
post  = Post.first
comment = post.comment.new
comment.description = "Some Text"
post.save
```

only the post gets saved. Instead, the comment doesn't seek any insertion although it has autosave enabled in the association.

As far as my understanding the above mentioned thing must work. But, its not working fine.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead?

Comment: I expect the code to do insert / update operation to the associated model say "Comment" of a post on saving like "post.save". 
But in my case only the Post model gets updated.